# Computer connects directly through modem but won't through router

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, router, home-networking, ethernet

I've get some problems that kept me from accessing internet on my computer for some time. So i spent the last 6 months using wireless connection on my laptop.

Yesterday, I bought a 20 meters ethernet cable and wired my computer to the router. Suddenly realizing it won't work at all.
I tried to debug with no success to isolate the problem.

Here are some valuable info:

- I tried to use an offboard ethernet board - no success (but this ethernet board
  works fine on my brother's computer)
- Also attaching the computer directly through modem - works fine, but I
  can't simply use the modem, since I share connection with some people.
- Two more computers are connected with the router with no problems.
- I tried using the same cable with another computer and it works perfectly.
- ipconfig /renew, ipconfig /flushdns, netsh resets, neither of these made it work.
- Can't connect on windows 7, nor ubuntu 10.04.
- On windows I got through services.msc and it seems that all remote access services are activated.
- I'm using windows firewall but tried to disable it with no success.
- Router DHCP is fine, and even trying to attach a static ip to the computer MAC address didn't work.

Any insights? I can't get my head around this problem. It's freaking me out!

Here are the contents of my ipconfig /all
Microsoft Windows [versão 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

```
C:\Users\Gtoknu>ipconfig /all

Configuração de IP do Windows

   Nome do host. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Gtoknu-PC
   Sufixo DNS primário . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Tipo de nó. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : híbrido
   Roteamento de IP ativado. . . . . . . . . . : sim
   Proxy WINS ativado. . . . . . . . . . . . . : não

Adaptador Ethernet Conexão local 6:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8139/810x Family Fas
t Ethernet NIC #3
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-08-54-AA-16-F1
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::7dba:5b64:17f0:a979%22(Pr
eferencial)
   Endereço IPv4 de Configuração Automática. . : 169.254.169.121(Preferencial)
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   IAID de DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 486541396
   DUID de Cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-5E-32-3C-00-21-9
7-83-49-E1
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                                 fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS em Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Habilitado

Adaptador Ethernet Conexão local 3:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce Networking Contro
ller #2
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-21-85-00-05-49
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sim
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel isatap.{24484914-92F6-460B-B52C-88C031C1749C}:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adaptador do Microsoft ISATAP
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel isatap.{57DE234A-89B8-4C7B-88E1-D98D9C792DEE}:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adaptador do Microsoft ISATAP #
2
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim

Adaptador de túnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Descrição . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interfa
ce
   Endereço Físico . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Não
   Configuração Automática Habilitada. . . . . : Sim
```

The adapter which the cabel is connected is `Ethernet Conexão local 6`.

Comment: when your pc is attached by cable to the router, run ipconfig /all and paste the contents in your question.

Comment: Just added it. It's in Portuguese but shouldn't be very hard to understand, since most things won't change at all.

Comment: even though I cant read it, the first thing I saw was 169.254.169.121.  That is an APIPA address.  That, and the fact there is no default gateway, means its not reaching the DHCP server.  Are you sure the cable your are using is good?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cable is fine. It works on other PCs and it even work when I connect mine through the modem.

Comment: have your tried a different port on the router?

Comment: Yup, no success too.

Comment: perhaps your NIC drive/settings are bad.  From the device manager, uninstall the ethernet card and then do a `scan for hardware changes` so it redectes in and reinstalls the drivers.

Comment: Just tried, it reinstalls the driver, but no success on getting connection.

Comment: strange.  if i were you I would try another cable, just to see if its the issue.  Yes you might have to move your PC, but it would eliminate one possible problem.

Comment: Tried with my brother's ethernet cable(which works in his PC), no success ):

Comment: well, that narrows it down to your ethernet card, driver, or pc setting.  Try burning a linux live CD, like Ubuntu or Mint and boot off of it.  If it works, than you know its not the card.

Comment: The router lease time is 120 minutes, there is a range of 99 ips (from 192.168.1.100 ~ 192.168.1.199), and DHCP is enabled.

Comment: I just couldnt connect on ubuntu too. It detects that the lan is cabled, but fails on connection.

Comment: interesting...  do you have another ethernet card you can try?

Comment: Right now I don't. But, I don't think the problem is in the card either. I tested it on the onboard nforce ethernet card, and it didn't worked. The offboard realtek ethernet card didnt managed to worked too.

Comment: from an administrator command prompt, run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: Here are the results of `sfc /scannow` generated through CBS.log: http://pastebin.com/8qt7kQrJ

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I have never seen a SFC log that long.  Well based on what I see from the results of the System File Checker, your Windows installation is corrupt.  The log is filled with corrupt files, many of which it wasnt able to fix, since the source was corrupt too.  I would run a scandisk and look for bad sectors; your disk might be damaged.  In the end, I think the best thing for you to do is back up your data and reinstall Windows.  Trying to fix it would most likely take way longer than just reinstalling.

Comment: That explains why it doenst work on ubuntu too?

Comment: well, no... The livecd test was just to see if it worked.  If it didnt, that could be a different issue.  But at this point, with Windows being corrupt, its impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting an APIPA address assigned to your interface which means the system cannot contact a DHCP server. Try resetting your router, making sure the WAN interface is cabled to the LAN interface of the modem. If you are using a modem/router configuration, putting your 2nd router in bridge mode and connecting the LAN port to another LAN port on the modem should resolve the problem

Comment: Already tried to reset the modem. Router and modem are properly cabled already. How can I put the router in bridge mode?

Comment: dont do that, thats not going to solve the problem

Comment: Sometimes the bridge mode function is esoterically named something conspicuous. It really depends on the model of your router. Bridge mode disables the routing capabilities on the router and basically turns it into a switch, allowing another device to handle routing.

So even though your PC is connected to your router, it would be getting an ip address through your modem - which seems to be working for you.

Before you do this though I am curious to know if disabling IPv6 on your network adapter settings would have any effect on the situation.

Comment: disabling IPv6 makes no apparent effect. And I actually need the router to work like a router. Can't simply pass the work out to the modem.